# Как вычислить Epoch time в Android API 24?

Tags: java, android, совместимость

Требуется конвертировать время LocalDateTime в величину long, т.е. в "epoch time" в приложении для API 24.
Android Studio предлагает использовать минимальную версию API 26, что мне не годится.
Как выяснилось, в API 24 метод LocalDateTime.toEpochSecond(zoneId) отсутствует. Мало того, метод LocalDateTime.now() тоже не работает!
Я пробовал улучшить обратную совместимость через [API desugaring][1]. Не помогло, хотя в списке поддерживаемых методов нужные мне присутствуют.
Что можно сделать?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.********.diplom"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Comment: Если не работает, то значит неправильно настроили. Приведите пример кода с требуемым поведением, gradle скрипт, также там требуется Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+

Comment: Надеюсь, что неправильно настроил. Сейчас попытаюсь разобраться как сюда выложить исходник.

Comment: `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true` забыли добавить в compileOptions

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает! Урра!